# data duplication in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i am uploading data to ELK server through JDBC input plugin in logstash. once i am uploading data to elastic server, when second time its uploading ,data duplication happens. i want to avoid that. 
Second thing is if i am using a document id in output section of logstash , then if some rows are updated but the key i am using as document id is the same , then ll it update that field? .

My requirement is i want to avoid data duplication and also want to update the fields which are updated even having same primary key value.

any help will be appreciated! thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to you the primary key of your DB record as the document ID if you want to avoir duplication. When the record gets updated, so will the document in ES.

Comment: thanks @val ...Able to avoid data duplication.Update thing i am checking.Thanks a lot for quick reply